# How can I loop traverse a graph through const reference in D?

Tags: constants, d, immutability

I have a loop traversing a graph using a 'const' reference but when I assign my iteration variable I realize that it is non-const then I get nice compiler's complains.

```d
class ClassDescriptor
{
    const string name;
    const TypeInfo type;
    const ClassDescriptor base;
    const IPropertyDescriptor[string] propertiesByName;

    IPropertyDescriptor getFlattenProperty(string name)
    {
        // This declaration makes 'const(ClassDescriptor) bag'
        // Note that in this point I can't add ref keyword.
        auto bag = this;
        while(!(bag is null))
        {
            if(name in bag.propertiesByName)
            {
                return bag.propertiesByName[name];
            }

            // This assigment breaks the constness
            bag = bag.base;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public this(string name, TypeInfo type, ClassDescriptor base, const IPropertyDescriptor[string] propertiesByName)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.base = base;
        this.propertiesByName = propertiesByName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pro tip: you can write `while (bag !is null)`. Same with `in`.

Comment: thanks! :)   I didnt know

Comment: I'm not a D programmer, but why can't you use pointers?

Comment: @Elazar because D classes are already reference types, so you'd introduce double indirection for no benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `std.typecons.Rebindable`:

http://dpldocs.info/experimental-docs/std.typecons.Rebindable.html

```
import std.typecons;
Rebindable!(const typeof(this)) bag = this;
```

then the rest should work the same.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the necessary `const` there.